# List of Arrays in Dynamo DB using Python and AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

List of Arrays in Dynamo DB using Python and AWS Lambda.
Can be stored as JSON in a field

How do I store this data(List of arrays) in Dynamo DB using Python and Lambda?
“Data”: {
“Items1”: [
“AAA”,
“BBB”
],
“Items2”: [
“CCC”,
“DDD”,
]
}

Answer (score 0):

Just store them in a Map type, you can store any type of JSON including nested arrays:

Example of multiple types:

```
{
    Day: "Monday",
    UnreadEmails: 42,
    ItemsOnMyDesk: [
        "Coffee Cup",
        "Telephone",
        {
            Pens: { Quantity : 3},
            Pencils: { Quantity : 2},
            Erasers: { Quantity : 1}
        }
    ]
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes